# How to Combine more than 4 Arrays in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a few separate arrays that I am trying to combine. When I have more than 4 arrays that I try to combine, it does not build and only gives the error `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`. I have tried it multiple different ways and am sure that it is only when I attempt to combine more than 4 arrays. Here is how I combine them:

For example let's say these are my arrays:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var b = [4, 6, 8, 10]
var c = [2, 4, 6, 8]
var d = [3, 6, 9, 12]
var e = [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Then I combine them and sort like this:

This works:

```
(a+b+c+d).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
```

But this does not and causes the build to fail:

```
(a+b+c+d+e).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
```

Is there a different way that I should go about combining these arrays to support the combination of more than 4?

Comment: *Where* are you doing this stuff? In the `body` of a SwiftUI view, or...?

Comment: Best to create `Chain5` and submit for inclusion in `Algorithms`. https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chain.md

Comment: A number doesn't have a name. Can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @West1 I am doing this in the body of a SwiftUI View, yes.

Answer (score 1):

the following works well for me on macos 11.4, xcode 12.5, target ios 14.5 and macCatalyst 11.3.
Show us exactly how you are using the code.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestErrorApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    var b = [4, 6, 8, 10]
    var c = [2, 4, 6, 8]
    var d = [3, 6, 9, 12]
    var e = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    var f = [4, 6, 8, 10]
    var g = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    var h = [2, 4, 6, 8]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("array combination").onAppear {
            let arr = (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h).sorted { $0 < $1 }
            print("----> arr: \(arr)")
        }
}
}
```